# ASP Razor: QuerySingle wrongly returns the same result

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

This piece of code should periodicaly request data from database:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refreshData() {
        @{
            var db2 = Database.Open("StarterSite");    
            string tresc2 = db2.QuerySingle(someQuery, 1).RoleName;


            <text>
                alert("@tresc2");

            </text>

        } 

    }
    setInterval(function() {refreshData()}, 5000);
```

What I do is:

- I run this code
- I change value in the database
- I expect to see alert with data changed

The problem is that alert displays the same value over and over again even once it changed.

What do I do wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: What is the query that you are executing?  What does the database table look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the alert will never change.  MVC renders the text when the request is made as

```
alert("whatever the value is on the first attempt");
```

If you hit view source in your browser, you'll see that in the HTML.  In order to actually get the new values, you'll have to go back down to the server with some ajax.

First, setup your json result in a controller:

```
public JsonResult GetNewResult()
{
    var db2 = Database.Open("StarterSite");    
    string tresc2 = db2.QuerySingle(someQuery, 1).RoleName;
    return this.Json(tresc2);
}
```

Then query it:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/Controller/GetNewResult",
  context: document.body
}).done(function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```